# Xamarin UITableViewController RowSelected not firing

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a storyboard in Xamarin Studio, which includes a `UITableViewController`. I have followed the examples and created a data source which inherits from `UITableViewSource`. The data source is assigned in the `ViewDidLoad`.

In the `UITableViewController`, I set the datasource (not the delegate). The data list appears, but when I click (in the Simulator) on a row, the `RowSelected` event handler does not fire.

I have tried hooking up the event handler myself in the `ViewDidLoad`:

```cs
this.RowSelected += TableView_RowSelected(this.TableView, this.TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow);
```

This results in a compile error saying that you cannot assign to `RowSelected` because it is a Method Group.

I notice that someone else on this site solved the same problem by removing the `base.RowSelected (tableView, indexPath);` from the event handler, but this does not work for me.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

`RowSelected` is a method and not a property that's why you can't assign it.

If you want to use `RowSelected`, override the method in the `TableViewController` or `TableViewSource`.

```cs
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath); 
}
```